# Spring mvc velocity springFormCheckboxes macro

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

Tried several different things but can't quite figure out how to feed the $path and $option parameters to springFormCheckboxes macro.

Macro source is here :

```
#macro( springFormCheckboxes $path $options $separator $attributes )
    #springBind($path)
    #foreach($option in $options.keySet())
        <input type="checkbox" name="${status.expression}" value="${option}" 
        #foreach($item in $status.actualValue)
            #if($item == $option) checked="checked" #end 
        #end
        ${attributes} #springCloseTag()
        ${options.get($option)} ${separator}
    #end
    <input type="hidden" name="_${status.expression}" value="on"/>
#end
```

Besides the origin of $status param that I keep seeing on spring macro's would also give me a good direction. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$path -> Implementation of a list, returns the string values of the selected checkboxes

$options -> Implementation of a map , should contain the checkbox texts as values, still have no idea what the keys are being used for.

There are suprisingly little usage examples for this.

spring mvc version -> 4.0.2.RELEASE